# return object with the same key and value from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`[1,2].reduce((accum,val) => ({val}) ,{})`

I expect above reduce function will return `{1:1, 2:2}` but it didn't, what's wrong? isn't I've return an object?

Answer (score 5):

You need to spread the accumulator (working with newer JS or with babeljs) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
console.log([1, 2].reduce((accum, val) => ({ ...accum, [val]: val }), {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1,2].reduce((accum,val) => { accum[val] = val
return accum } ,{})
```

This will do the trick. You weren't referencing the starting object.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `Object.assign` to add new property and values

```js
var result = [1, 2].reduce((accum, val) => Object.assign(accum, {[val]: val}), {})
console.log(result);
```

Doc: [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 0):

Use can write like this:
You need to spread accumulator value.

```
[1,2].reduce((accum,val) => ({...accum, [val]:val}) ,{})
```